# Date pipe shows wrong date and time in Linux

Tags: django, angular

I am using date pipe `date:'short'`.For storing the time ,I am using timezone.now().For displaying the time to the user in the UI,I am using like

`<span>{{dat.last_heard_time|date:'short'}}</span>` in the template file.

I am using two OS in the same machine.I am doing all this things that is storing in DB,template file everything in Windows.

The windows machine shows the correct time but while running the same page in Linux's mozilla/chrome,it result wrong time and date

**DB( in windows)**:2019-11-14 16:56:06.503

**Windows's Chrome**:11/14/19, 5:00 PM(shows the time in Window system i.e 5 PM)(**CORRECT**)

**Linux's Chrome**:11/15/19, 6:30 AM(Actual time in Linux system 17.00)(**WRONGLY DISPLAY**)

Help me with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

in your django settings file add your time zone

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'
```

For example this is for India

Comment: It also give a wrong output both in windows and linux

Comment: in which time zone you are?

Comment: IST (Indian Standard TIme )only